# error: narrowing conversion of '-1' from 'int' to 'long unsigned int' [-Wnarrowing] while compiling `gcc`

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, gcc-warning

I was compiling the final [`gcc-9.2.0`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-9.2.0/gcc-9.2.0.tar.xz) build using [`glibc-2.31`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.31.tar.xz) while following [this article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source) with `make && make install` when I came across the following error messages:

```
In file included from ../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer
_platform_limits_posix.cc:193:
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_internal_defs.h:339:7
2: error: narrowing conversion of '-1' from 'int' to 'long unsigned int'
[-Wnarrowing]
  339 | IMPL_PASTE(assertion_failed_##_, line)[2*(int)(pred)-1]
      |                                                       ^

../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_internal_defs.h:333:3
0: note: in expansion of macro 'IMPL_COMPILER_ASSERT'
  333 | #define COMPILER_CHECK(pred) IMPL_COMPILER_ASSERT(pred, __LINE__)
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix
.h:1511:3: note: in expansion of macro 'COMPILER_CHECK'
 1511 |   COMPILER_CHECK(sizeof(((__sanitizer_##CLASS *) NULL)->MEMBER) =
= \
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix
.cc:1161:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CHECK_SIZE_AND_OFFSET'
 1161 | CHECK_SIZE_AND_OFFSET(ipc_perm, mode);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_internal_defs.h:339:7
0: warning: size of array 'assertion_failed__1161' is not an integral con
stant-expression [-Wpedantic]
  339 | r IMPL_PASTE(assertion_failed_##_, line)[2*(int)(pred)-1]
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_internal_defs.h:333:3
0: note: in expansion of macro 'IMPL_COMPILER_ASSERT'
  333 | #define COMPILER_CHECK(pred) IMPL_COMPILER_ASSERT(pred, __LINE__)
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix
.h:1511:3: note: in expansion of macro 'COMPILER_CHECK'
 1511 |   COMPILER_CHECK(sizeof(((__sanitizer_##CLASS *) NULL)->MEMBER) =
= \
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix
.cc:1161:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CHECK_SIZE_AND_OFFSET'
 1161 | CHECK_SIZE_AND_OFFSET(ipc_perm, mode);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_internal_defs.h:339:7
0: error: size '-1' of array 'assertion_failed__1161' is negative
  339 | r IMPL_PASTE(assertion_failed_##_, line)[2*(int)(pred)-1]
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_internal_defs.h:333:3
0: note: in expansion of macro 'IMPL_COMPILER_ASSERT'
  333 | #define COMPILER_CHECK(pred) IMPL_COMPILER_ASSERT(pred, __LINE__)
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix
.h:1511:3: note: in expansion of macro 'COMPILER_CHECK'
 1511 |   COMPILER_CHECK(sizeof(((__sanitizer_##CLASS *) NULL)->MEMBER) =
= \
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix
.cc:1161:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CHECK_SIZE_AND_OFFSET'
 1161 | CHECK_SIZE_AND_OFFSET(ipc_perm, mode);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[4]: *** [Makefile:663: sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/sayakbrm/sbos/sources/gcc-9.2.0/gcc-bui
ld/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:527: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sayakbrm/sbos/sources/gcc-9.2.0/gcc-bui
ld/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:414: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sayakbrm/sbos/sources/gcc-9.2.0/gcc-bui
ld/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libsanitizer'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:12361: all-target-libsanitizer] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sayakbrm/sbos/sources/gcc-9.2.0/gcc-bui
ld'
make: *** [Makefile:962: all] Error 2
```

I have already managed to compile the stage 1 `gcc` and `glibc`, and this error occurs only when building the final pass of `gcc`.

Comment: This isn't a `linux-from-scratch` question. What does `echo $LJOS_HOST && echo $LJOS_ENDIAN` output?

Comment: @rfmodulator sorry, removed the tag. The output is `x86_64-cross-linux-gnu` and `little`.

Comment: It happens... okay, one more: `echo $LJOS`?

Comment: @rfmodulator `/home/sayakbrm/sbos`, whcih happens to be another hdd which I mounted to that location: `/dev/sdb1 :   /home/sayakbrm/sbos`

Comment: Okay, good. Someone else might know how to solve the error you're seeing, but the likely problem is that you're using old instructions to build newer packages. (You jumped two majors for GCC, that's a big deal...) So I think you should go back to the beginning, use the package versions that are specified, and carefully follow the directions (I have no reason to think that you're not.) Once you're successful building it verbatim, then you can start to customize it  and work through those challenges. And you should checkout `Linux From Scratch` http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/

Comment: @rfmodulator thanks for the advice! I did think of getting an LFS system up, and plan on using this system just as a stepping stone.

Comment: @rfmodulator thanks for mentioning LFS, the solution to this exact problem happened to be in the manual and is caused by using glibc-2.31: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439284/5961780

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above error occurs due to a problem introduced by using Glibc-2.31.

The problem can be fixed with the following command:

```
sed -e '1161 s|^|//|' \
    -i libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc
```

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20200723122730/http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/gcc-pass2.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the "source" link appears to be broken (checked on May 16th 2021).

Do you remember which version of the LinuxFromScratch your link was pointing to at the time of your post?

Comment: @Patrick LFS9.1... Check this link for reference https://web.archive.org/web/20200723122730/http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/gcc-pass2.html

Comment: What is the "problem introduced by Glibc-2.31"? I.e. why `CHECK_SIZE_AND_OFFSET(ipc_perm, mode)` leads to assertion failed?

Answer (score 1):

GCC's libsanitizer needs to be ported to this glibc change:

- [ipc_perm struct's mode member has wrong type in sys/ipc.h](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18231)

This happened in [GCC PR 92154: new glibc breaks arm bootstrap due to libsanitizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92154), which is included in GCC 9.3, but not in GCC 9.2.